# R error: attempt to apply non-function , randomForest , rfImpute

Tags: r, random-forest

Trying to work around Random forest in R.

```
rf<- randomForest(train$Loan_Status~., data=train,  mtry=5,importance=TRUE, ntree=200,na.action=rfImpute(train$Loan_Status ~., train),allowParallel=TRUE)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: question is R error that i am getting "attempt to apply non-function"

Comment: this code 
 rf<- randomForest(train$Loan_Status~., data=train, mtry=5,importance=TRUE, ntree=200,na.action=rfImpute(train$Loan_Status ~., train),allowParallel=TRUE)

is ending up in error "attempt to apply non-function"

Comment: No, I got the error "object train not found" ;) Could you please provide a reproducable example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Here is the full code
+++++++++++++++++
train = read.csv(file.choose(),,na.strings=c("NA",""))
test = read.csv(file.choose(),,na.strings=c("NA","")) 
library(randomForest)
train$Loan_Status<-factor(as.numeric(train$Loan_Status))
train = train[,-1]
set.seed(222)
train$Loan_Status<-factor(as.numeric(train$Loan_Status))
rf<- randomForest(train$Loan_Status~., data=train, mtry=5,importance=TRUE, ntree=200,na.action=rfImpute(train$Loan_Status ~., train),allowParallel=TRUE) 
++++
 You Need to use a data file "train" and IDK how can i provide u that .

Comment: update your question, don't put additional code in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

na.action does not work like that, it takes a function such as na.fail or na.omit as input.

Try to use rfImpute as in documented example

```
data(iris)
iris.na <- iris
set.seed(111)
## artificially drop some data values.
for (i in 1:4) iris.na[sample(150, sample(20)), i] <- NA
set.seed(222)
iris.imputed <- rfImpute(Species ~ ., iris.na)
set.seed(333)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris.imputed)
print(iris.rf)
```